# Data Scraping using python And bs4

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="/news/2018/05/israeli-army-projectiles-fired-israel-gaza-180529051139606.html">
    <h2 class="top-sec-title">
        Israel launches counterattacks in Gaza amid soaring tensions
    </h2>
</a>
```

I want to use the class of `h2` that is "top-sec-title" and scrape the text on h2 with href of a.
The example below is what I have been dealing this below html has a class of `a` tag which helped me getting href also the text in its child element that is `h3` in the bellow case:

```
<a class="gs-c-promo-heading gs-o-faux-block-link__overlay-link gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__anchor" href="/news/world-us-canada-44294366">
    <h3 class="gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text">
        Hurricane Maria 'killed 4,600 in Puerto Rico'
    </h3>
</a>
```

The code below is what I used to extract data from the html source above.

```
news = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'gs-c-promo-heading gs-o-faux-block- 
link__overlay-link gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__anchor'})

for item in news:
    print(item.get(href))
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the all the elements that enclose `h2` elements, which will allow you to get the `href` if the enclosing element is an `a`.

```
lst_of_h2 = soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'top-sec-title'})
for h2 in lst_of_h2:
    h2.parent # enclosing element
```

Comment: Notice that `h2` tag has no siblings. You probably meant to use `.parent`.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
html = '''
<a href="/news/2018/05/israeli-army-projectiles-fired-israel-gaza-180529051139606.html">
    <h2 class="top-sec-title">
        Israel launches counterattacks in Gaza amid soaring tensions
    </h2>
</a>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

a_tags = [h.parent for h in soup.select('.top-sec-title')]

for a in a_tags:
    print(a['href'])
    print(a.get_text(strip=True))
```

**Output:**

```
/news/2018/05/israeli-army-projectiles-fired-israel-gaza-180529051139606.html
Israel launches counterattacks in Gaza amid soaring tensions
```